# Sub query or Join in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables  `ca_contact`, `usp_contact`

The columns of `ca_contact` table are

```
Last_name nvarchr[200],contact_uuid  binary[16] ,contact_type  [int]
```

The columns of `usp_contact` table are

```
Contact_uuid binary [16],zteam binary[16]
```

**Executing**:

```
SELECT top 2 CA.LAST_NAME , USP.ZTEAM 
FROM ca_contact AS CA
JOIN usp_contact AS USP 
ON CA.contact_uuid = USP.contact_uuid
AND CA.contact_type = '2308'
```

**Results in**

```
Group   Team
Team
PCS_Data Request    0x4B5355B05E7F3F4383FDD4C9C211BC2A
Workplace Services-One Team 0x255C787ED0499841B6FB5003CDE44D8B
```

I want to replace the Team value with corresponding last_name.

**Example**

```
SELECT LAST_NAME FROM ca_contact 
WHERE contact_uuid = 0x4B5355B05E7F3F4383FDD4C9C211BC2A
```

**Results**

```
LAST_NAME
Solutions Team
```

Note: for every group record there will be a corresponding one team in `usp_contact` which will store in binary format, for every team record there will detail information `ca_contact`.

The primary key here is `contact_uuid`.

Finally I want the output like

```
Group_name | Team_Name
```

Comment: if they are related then join

Comment: Ambiguous question.. Where is the Group_name and Team_Name read from?
Is the LAST_NAME = GROUP_NAME???

Comment: Yep, group_name and team_name  are alias of last_name.

Comment: succeeded to get the desired out put by joining the tabels